# What do you call this kind of design with stripes with rounded corners

Tags: shapes, illustration, style-identification

What's the name that classifies this style (the black rounded lines)?

[image]

([Source](https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/meetups/meetup-photo-5-196220270f1455da5c68cd053144e4c5162f9817fe8435e5492295b1ca47ae55.jpg))

I've also made a variant without actually knowing what it's called.

[image]

Comment: not everything has a name

Comment: Technically not actual design, but illustration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time it's refered to as **The Rounded Wavy Pattern**, but it has no real name as far as I know.

[It was used for the first time](https://medium.com/@geometrieva/tutorial-for-that-space-illustration-you-keep-seeing-around-9c97214b4d92), or at least its popularity started in 2013 with this illustration by Nina Geometrieva :

[image: Meteor by Nina Geometrieva]

([Dribbble shot](https://dribbble.com/shots/1323389-Meteor))

Answer (score 0):

There is not a specific word in my knowledge. But you can make it in very easy way, 
1.Just select what shape you want to have strips on it
2.make two groups of strips with rounded corner one with the same color as your shape and other with 100% transparency
3. Now add colored strips with your shape and difference transparent strips from your shape

Comment: I think this designs style is called vanilla design

Comment: Yes I know how to make it, the last (dribbble) shot is mine but I was just confused that I don't know what to call it tbh

Answer (score 0):

You could call this a "**gooey line illustration**". Not many relevant images come up if you search for that, but you can get a lot of examples and tutorials if you search "**[CSS gooey effect](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+gooey+effect&rlz=1CAACAJ_enUS664US664&oq=css++gooey+effect&aqs=chrome.0.0.2784j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it has an official name in the way that "plaid" does, but  "rounded lines pattern" will turn the pattern/style up more often than not.

Comment: @Danielillo I disagree with your flag as "not an answer"