# What kind of art style does Kurzgesagt use?

Tags: illustration, style-identification, style, graphic-styles, art

Kurzgesagt has a very distinctive, vector-based animation style that uses lots of gradients and an attractive, high-saturation colour palette.

My question is, what kind of art style is this?

I understand that it is modern, but could someone more knowledgeable than myself please help me analyze the style? I'm looking for Googleable words that will help me explore and discover similar art styles.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsXVk37bltHxD1rDPwtNM8Q

[image: People uncomfortable squeezed together in a tight space]

[image: "Egoistic Altruism" YouTube video preview image. A vector image of planet earth, sectioned into two parts. It is burning on the left half, but is green on the right half, with flowers]

[image: Screenshot from Kurzgesagt video, comets and space ships against a backdrop filled with stars and planets]

Comment: We had a question like this before (like your last image) I can't find it right now.

Comment: I am compelled to say this. "Modern" is not "modern" at all, as a historical period, it starts in the 16th century. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_history
As "Modern art" it is the series of artistic movements from late 19th century to the 1970s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_art

Comment: @WELZ this question? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/93682/what-do-you-call-this-kind-of-design-with-stripes-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 3):

It's just **flat illustration**.

To achieve a more defined search, in some sites they define it by the type of color, calling it **[Flat Neon Color Illustration](https://www.google.es/search?q=neon%20colors%20flat%20illustration&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CTscLy7rdSXyIjhTKl4lj9VCQ4hLUXsR9kzdl4R_1zEOrOEiJQXqzFHh7a4HV-ys8IBqolvNdFMl8D8wJhMm4JqfylioSCVMqXiWP1UJDERXRJttsVzxMKhIJiEtRexH2TN0RjActfpWbHVMqEgmXhH_1MQ6s4SBEP9OEoD03G3CoSCYlBerMUeHtrEUXUgBepCPb8KhIJgdX7KzwgGqgR_1oGGToMog9UqEgmW810UyXwPzBEJkUh9jQ23LCoSCQmEybgmp_1KWEUm3CsbWr2x4&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWmND4_73eAhUK6RoKHdbEB_cQ9C96BAgBEBs)**.

---

[Lovepik.com](https://lovepik.com/images/illustration-flat-neon-color.html): **Flat Neon Color**

---

*[Shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-bright-neon-colors-web-banner-374233258)*

[image]

---

*[Adobe Stock](https://stock.adobe.com/ee/images/night-city-silhouettes-of-buildings-with-neon-glow-and-vivid-colors-at-night-city-landscape-template-flat-style-illustration-in-neon-vivid-colors-cityscape-background-urban-life/222972734)*

[image: Adobe]

Answer (score 1):

While your examples show a clear and popular style, I'll be very surprised if there's a name for it. I would probably call it minimalistic, but that's still a very general term. Some buzzwords you could use while searching for this style is simplistic, flat, and modern (as you've already pointed out). It's also common for this style to have minimal curves and simple angles, such as all angles in the illustration being 45 degrees.

Also as side note, this is technically (and probably arguably) an illustration style and not graphic design. The 2 can have overlap but it's worth noting for future reference so it'll be easier to find what you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: I seen where you pointed out the gradients and I see them in the examples. Some of the examples are still a flat illustration style, though.

Answer (score -3):

It’s a distinct style, but the technique is common. It’s called vector art because it uses digital curves with tangent handles for controlling shape which are created from algorithms for splines. Adobe Illustrator, is good software to generate them, and Adobe After Effects can then be used for the animation.

Comment: it's obviously vector art, it's already stated in the question. Check [answer] if you want to learn more about the site, and take the [tour].